# Admin page won't show

Tags: php, css

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at/admin/index.php:21) in
>   /var/www/web143366/html/admin/index.php on line 24

```
   <?php
require_once('../config.php');
require_once('../php/functions.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Admin Panel</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../layout.css">
</head>

<body>


<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    header('Location: /admin/login');
} else {

?>

<div id="leftPanel">
<a href="/"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Homepage</div></a>
    <a href="/admin"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina active">Dashboard</div></a>
    <a href="accounts"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Manage Accounts</div></a>
    <a href="addAccount"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Add Account</div></a>
    <a href="addCategory"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Add Category</div></a>
    <a href="messages"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Messages</div></a>
    <a href="logout"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Logout</div></a>
</div>

<div id="rightPanel">
    <h3>Recent payments</h3>
    <table>
    <tr class='first'>
        <td width='20%'>Account Login</td>
        <td width='20%'>Account Password</td>
        <td width='20%'>Date</td>
        <td width='20%'>Amount</td>
        <td width='20%'>Payment ID</td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT accounts.login AS Login, accounts.password AS Pass, date, amount, paymentID FROM payments INNER JOIN accounts ON payments.accountId=accounts.id order by date DESC');
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td width='20%'>" . $row['Login'] ."</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['Pass'] ."</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['date'] ."</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['amount'] ."$</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['paymentID'] ."</td></tr>";
    }

    ?>
    </table>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>




<?php

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit all: This is the error. When I remove line 24 I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
>   /var/www/web143366/html/admin/login.php on line 32
>   Line 32: `$result = $sql->get_result();`

Code:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>Wrong email or password</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $p = $row['password'];
            $uid = $row['id'];
        }

        if (password_verify($pass, $p)) {
            $_SESSION['adminid'] = $uid;
            header('Location: /admin');
        } else {
            echo "<h1>Wrong email or password 2</h1>";
        }
    }
}
```

Login.php=

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');
require_once('../php/functions.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Admin Panel</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['loginBtn'])) {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);


    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>Wrong email or password</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $p = $row['password'];
            $uid = $row['id'];
        }

        if (password_verify($pass, $p)) {
            $_SESSION['adminid'] = $uid;
            header('Location: /admin');
        } else {
            echo "<h1>Wrong email or password 2</h1>";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['forgotBtn'])) {
    $code = randomChars(20);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $email);
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>No user with that email</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $uid = $row['id'];
        }
        $sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO resetpass (userID, code) VALUES (?, ?)');
        $sql->bind_param('ss', $uid, $code);
        $sql->execute();

        $message = "Your reset link: " . "http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/admin/login?r=' . $code;
        $to = $email;
        $title = "Reset Password";
        if (sendEmail($to, $message, $title)) {
            echo "Email with reset code has been sent";
        } else {
            echo "Error while sending email";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['resetBtn'])) {
    $nPass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nPass']);
    $code = $_POST['code'];

    $password = password_hash($nPass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM resetpass WHERE code = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('s', $code);
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows < 1) {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $uid = $row['userID'];
        }
        $sql = $conn->prepare('UPDATE resetpass SET used = "1" WHERE code = ?');
        $sql->bind_param('s', $code);
        $sql->execute();

        $sql = $conn->prepare('UPDATE admin SET password = ? WHERE id = ?');
        $sql->bind_param('ss', $password, $uid);
        $sql->execute();

        echo "Password changed successfuly, you can now login";
    }
}




?>

<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    if (isset($_GET['forgot'])) { ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Account Email Address:</div>
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email address" required>
        <input type="submit" name="forgotBtn" value="Reset">
    </form> 

<?php } else if (isset($_GET['r'])) { ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">New Password:</div>
        <input type="password" name="nPass" placeholder="New password" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $_GET['r'] ?>" required>
        <input type="submit" name="resetBtn" value="Reset">
    </form> 

<?php
    } else { ?>
        <h2 style="text-align: left;">Login to admin panel</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Email Address:</div>
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email address" required>
        <div class="formularzowyNaglowek">Password:</div>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit" name="loginBtn" value="Login">
        </form> 
        <a href="/admin/login?forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
<?php
    }
} else {
    header('Location: /admin');
}





?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 500 status indicates a server side error.  Nothing to do with the client side, we can't tell you anything about the error with the information that you have provided.  You will need to provide the server logs for any help

Comment: I already tought so yeah...But I can't find logs on this hoster:https://flatbooster.com/

Comment: Look at your code.  Start taking stuff out until you get a successful page load.  Your code is generating an unhandled exception, which is why the server renders a 500 status

Comment: Edit for the error code ! Will this help more ? :S

Answer (score 0):

The line `header('Location: /admin/login');` will redirect to the login page when the user is not logged in.
The problem is, that the function `header()` doesnt work when there has been content outputted already (echo or html).

```
<?php
session_start(); // only if you havent called session_start in config.php or functions.php
require_once('../config.php');
require_once('../php/functions.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 
    header('Location: /admin/login');
    exit();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Admin Panel</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../layout.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="leftPanel">
<a href="/"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Homepage</div></a>
    <a href="/admin"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina active">Dashboard</div></a>
    <a href="accounts"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Manage Accounts</div></a>
    <a href="addAccount"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Add Account</div></a>
    <a href="addCategory"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Add Category</div></a>
    <a href="messages"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Messages</div></a>
    <a href="logout"><div class="przyciskPanelAdmina">Logout</div></a>
</div>

<div id="rightPanel">
    <h3>Recent payments</h3>
    <table>
    <tr class='first'>
        <td width='20%'>Account Login</td>
        <td width='20%'>Account Password</td>
        <td width='20%'>Date</td>
        <td width='20%'>Amount</td>
        <td width='20%'>Payment ID</td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT accounts.login AS Login, accounts.password AS Pass, date, amount, paymentID FROM payments INNER JOIN accounts ON payments.accountId=accounts.id order by date DESC');
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td width='20%'>" . $row['Login'] ."</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['Pass'] ."</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['date'] ."</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['amount'] ."$</td><td width='20%'>" . $row['paymentID'] ."</td></tr>";
    }

    ?>
    </table>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put up my whole index/login for the admin panel... So you can have a full look at it... I replaced my code with urs : from session_start to exit but it doesnt work. It will ignore the session start because there is already one.